# How to properly notify a data bound control that a composite property has new value?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have bound an information label to a public property in my view model. The property is composite, i.e. it's got multiple backing fields.

```
private String back1;
private String back2;
public String Front { get { return back1 + back2; } }
```

In the process, a user clicks a button, which fires an event that sets a value to *Something*. That part works just dandy. So I jacked in assignment to the two backing fields in there too, as follows.

```
public Thing Something
{
  ...
  set
  {
    ...
    back1 = getBack1();
    back2 = getBack2();
    OnPropertyChanged();
  }
}
```

The problem is that the label that's data bound to *Front*, doesn't change. I need to tell the system that it's dirty and needs a refresh. However, since I didn't use any properties for the backing fields (hence, the property *Front* is never **set**, just rendered), I can't use *OnPropertyChanged* method.

Was it a bad design and should I use two different properties for that? Seems wasteful to bind two things that **always** will produce a common output. How else can I go about it?

Comment: Call OnpropertyChanged("Front") in the set method for the Somthing property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bindings work by listening for `PropertyChanged` *based on the property name*. So you need to notify for the property that you want the UI to "get". So the method needs to be called **twice**. Once for each property to be notified of the need for update. In the setter, there should be the following.

```
OnPropertyChanged("Front");
OnPropertyChanged("Something");
```

The second call, if performed from the scope of the property's setter of *Something* can be parameterless as the standard version of that method in .NET 4.5 uses the `[CallerMemberName]` attribute, which allows you to do:

```
OnPropertyChanged();
```

From the setter of the property *without* specifying the name. Note that the compiler is just putting the name of the calling property there for you, *its still there*. There is no valid raising of `PropertyChanged` without the property name.

Comment: Bradley m8 he doesn't have a setter for "public String Front" isn't that the issue here? (a setter and OnpropertyChanged of course)

Comment: @Sag1v He doesn't need a setter. OneWay bindings will work with just a getter. His code is perfectly valid on that front

Comment: got you. well an empty OnPropertyChanged() will raise the event for property "Something" and not "Front" anyway...

Comment: @Sag1v Thats true, it will raise it for the property that invoked it. This is actually the one flaw of `[CallerMemberName]`, as it makes it easier to make this mistake.

Comment: I'll take the liberty of adding something to your reply that is the actual thingy that resolved it for me. Feel free to adapt and change the edition, should you feel it deteriorates the quality of your contribution.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Thanks for the edit! Since there was some repitition, I merged the two together. Let me know if you would like something changed!

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Can't get any better than this. +1 for the extra effort.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the Property name to that method:

```
OnPropertyChanged("Front");
```

check this [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that link but it's not **precisely** spot-on to my question because **that example** also works with empty parenthesis (since they're updating the property itself and notifying about **that very same** property. Check the comment from Jens - he's got the right hint (for some reason posted as a comment not a reply, though, so I can't accept it). If you rewrite your reply I'll check it as the right answer, though.

Comment: I was referring to Front property I thought you knew it can't be change like that with not a proper setter that raising  the OnPropertyChanged

Comment: Where is the sense in this discussion? Just pass the **right** property name, and of course **in addition** to `OnPropertyChanged()` (or  `OnPropertyChanged("Something")`) , which notifies about the change of the `Something` property. I've edited the answer.

Comment: @KonradViltersten See my answer for why `OnPropertyChanged()` works. Its still actually passing the name.

Comment: @Sag1v I meant that the edit should be done in the reply, not just mentioned in the comments. As it looks right now, a less experience (or less gifted, hehe) developer might not see the actual answer helping out. The answer is in there, true, but I believe that the future readers might behoove from it being made more obvious and pedagogic.

Comment: @Clemens Your comment is spot on. I'm a little bit surprised that you didn't put **that** when you edited the reply. That's exactly the answer, since calling *OnPropertyChanged* **twice** is the part when one can raise the eye browse (when seeing it for the first time). Keep in mind that not everybody is as savvy as you so something obvious might be perceived as much less so to others. The pain of being really good at something, you know...   :)